# How to hide a Many2one field without any dependecies?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-11

I want to make a field invisible but without any other dependencies.

```
<field name="days_before" attrs="{'invisible': [('object', '=', '5')]}"/>
```

So without `[('object', '=', '5')]`
Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a field invisible without any condition is much easier syntax.

`<field name="days_before" invisible="1"/>`

Same syntax works for readonly. Either value `1` or `True` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can add invisible="1" in the xml file like:

```
<field name="field_name" invisible="1"/>
```

Also if you have inherited the view you can make an inherited field invisible without conditions by adding in the xml file:

```
<field name="field_name" position="attributes">
    <attribute name='invisible'>1</attribute>
</field>
```